# the asterisk before variable in objective-c,what does it really mean?

Tags: objective-c

```
BOOL bl = YES;
BOOL *bl_pointer = &bl;

*bl_pointer = NO;

NSLog(@"bl is %@", bl?@"YES": @"NO");



NSString *st;
st = @"ss";

NSLog(@"%@ is a string", st);
```

I am recently learning Objective-C and get confused:shoudn't it be

```
*st = @"ss";
```

like

```
*bl_pointer = NO;
```

since st is also a pointer ,like bl_pointer, Or am I missing anything?

And What's the meaning of "all variables in Objective-C are pointers"?

Comment: ObjC is superset of C, so you have to understand C first.

Comment: This was helpful for me in understanding the asterisk: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-beginners-guide-to-objective-c-language-and-variables

Answer (score 1):

The statement "all variables in Objective-C are pointers" is false.

All objc objects are allocated on the heap, and are referenced via pointers (that's not technically true either, because of tagged pointers and such, but it's good enough until you gain a better understanding).

Native C types (e.g., integral types and structs) are treated as they would be in C.

`NSString` is an objective C object.  Thus, you need a pointer.

```
// This is a C type -- not an objc object.
BOOL bl = YES;

// This is a pointer to a BOOL, initialized to point to bl
BOOL *bl_pointer = &bl;

// Dereference a pointer to assign NO to what is being pointed to
*bl_pointer = NO;

// NSString is an objc object, and variables must be pointers
NSString *st;

// You are now pointing to a NSString with the value "ss"
// The confusion may be due to the @"" syntax, which just means that
// there is some NSString object, that has the value "ss" and it is
// being assigned to st.  Note, you read about memory management as well.
st = @"ss";
```

I suggest you get a good introductory book, as these are very basic questions.

Comment: so,the @"ss" is a pointer, which points to a heap place where it holds the value of "ss",and the @ is like &?

Comment: `@` is a special objc token to denote objc special syntax.  When used with objects, it will "box" them appropriately... again, this is an oversimplification.  @"something" results in a `NSString` @1123 results in a `NSNumber`.  These may or may not be objects that are allocated on the heap, but they will be pointers to objc objects.